# Move a rectangle down using Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I'm newbie in Java and I want to move a rectangle down in a JFrame. I want to see this movement.

Why can't I see the rectangle moving down? Do I have to use other library or what?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.lang.Thread;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Draw extends JComponent {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 128, 128, 128));

        try {
            for(int i = 70; i < 100; i++) {
                g.fillRect(40, i, 100, 70);
                Thread.sleep(10); // To see the moviment.
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        setSize(300, 200);

        Draw draw = new Draw();
        add(draw);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swing is single threaded

This means that if you perform any long running or blocking operations within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, you will prevent Swing from performing any painting operations or processing using input

## Swing is not thread safe

This means that you should never try and update the UI, or any state the UI relies on, from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this can run you into all kinds of weirdness and unpredictable states

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details

## A simple solution...

Possibly the simplest solution is to use a Swing `Timer`, for example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Draw());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Draw extends JPanel {

        private int yPos = 0;

        public Draw() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    yPos += 1;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 128, 128, 128));
            g2d.fillRect(40, yPos, 100, 70);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

> Why use a `JPanel` over a `JComponent`?

For simplicity.  A `JPanel` will paint it's background (using the background property) automatically (if you call `super.paintComponent`) saving your the hassle

Answer (score -1):

Your "time" consideration is not following Swing UI threading concept.

Think of it this way: Swing has a `Frame`, you paint the content, then wait for something to change, and paint again.

A suggestion could be a Thread, that every x milliseconds, requests the JFrame to update its content and then by using `repaint()` method.

An example:

```
Draw() {
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Move x and y of the desired rectangle and request repaint
        x+=10;
        repaint();
    }}, 50);
}
```